# Where can I get an official verification whether a transit visa is required?

Tags: transit-visas

I am a Indian Citizen and will be travelling to Lyon (France). Right now, I am just checking various flights. I haven't decided, as  most of the flights transit through a Schengen country, Middle Eastern country, or Russia.

I want to be sure about the transit visa requirements in each country before making flight reservations. While I've checked transit visa requirements of many countries, most of these answers are from forums. I keep seeing posts that say "as long as you are not leaving the airport you do not require a transit visa," which is not necessarily the case.

I do understand that it depends on your nationality and duration of layover, but I want to find the genuine source to get the answer regarding transit visa of a country.

Comment: If you're going to France, you must already have a Schengen visa, and obviously do not need another one to transit in Schengen.

Comment: @jpatokal: The only part that might make this not a duplicate is that this OP is asking for official verification. Many online resources will be compilations with no guarantees that they are error-free and 100% up-to-date. OP might want a method rather than a resource.

Comment: @hippietrail I'm not sure how much more official you can get than the IATA Travelcentre, which is the 1st answer...

Comment: @jpatokal: OK sorry that's perfect then. Probably (-:

Comment: This question is about Transit and one important detail TravelCentre lacks is the Airport.  LHR has a Transit area while LTN (AFAIK) does not.  That can make a notable difference.